# Listing SoftLayer invoice greater than a date and time

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have a SoftLayer invoice which has "**createDate**" value of "**2016-08-23T14:21:29-05:00**".  (** Note the 5 hour offset).

I use **SoftLayer_Account::getInvoices()** API with an Object Filter set like below:

```
$filter = new stdClass();
$filter->invoices = new stdClass();
$filter->invoices->createDate = new stdClass();
$filter->invoices->createDate->operation = 'greaterThanDate';
$filter->invoices->createDate->options = array();
$filter->invoices->createDate->options[0] = new stdClass();
$filter->invoices->createDate->options[0]->name = 'date';
$filter->invoices->createDate->options[0]->value = array($searchDateTime->format('m/d/Y H:i:s'));
$slClient->setObjectFilter($filter);
$result = $slClient->getInvoices();
```

It used to be that the date that I specify in this query, I can add the 5 hour time offset to the date and time shown in createDate and still get this invoice.  (i.e. I would query for dates greater than "2016-08-23T19:21:00" and the invoice with "createDate" value of "2016-08-23T14:21:29-05:00" is included in the result).

But I noticed starting about 8/22/2016, I have to subtract 5 hour time offset from my usual query date and time in order for the same invoice to show up in the result. (i.e. Now I have to query for dates greater than  "2016-08-23T14:21:00" in order for the invoice with "createDate" value of "2016-08-23T14:21:29-05:00" to be included in the result.

Do you see the difference?  I hope I am being clear about the description of the behavior change.
Now I have to use the createDate date and time value ignoring the time offset value vs. before I had to consider the time offset value.

Is this a bug?
or is this a permanent change?

Comment: The data in the database of softlayer is saved using the Dallas time zone, the data displayed by the Api is coneverted to the timezone which has been configured for that specific user that is using the Api. So if the user which is getting the the invoices has a different timezone you need to take in account that difference in your query. My questión is: are you sure that all users that are calling the get invoices have the same timezone -5?

Comment: I am sorry, but that logic just doesn't make much sense.  So I have to know which time zone each customer is and adjust the query?  Please explain with with examples.  The customer that I used is in US Eastern zone and I had to use -5 hour on the API call.  Another co-worker in US Central timezone used a customer in US Central also had to use -5 to get expected result.  Please explain in more detail and is this a new change and is it a permanent change?

Comment: it always worked like that, I did not hear any change about that, so you are sure that the your users that are using the API have the same timezone configured in his Users profiles (https://control.softlayer.com/account/user/profile) right? you may getting the issue because the timezone there has been changed.

Comment: All I can tell you is that we've been using this same API with same time (without -5 hours) and it had been working fine all these time then noticed few days ago that we need to put -5 hours to get the same result.  I just checked couple of user profiles.  Even though their address is in US Eastern, the time zone seems to be set to Dallas, TX time.  I don't know why or how that happened, but I know I've never went in and changed.  If somehow it was always set to Dallas, TX time zone, I had to use -5 hours even before, but I know it worked before without the -5 hours.

Comment: Or maybe somehow SoftLayer internally changed the time zone of all customers for some reason?  Could you do me a favor and try this?  Create a customer at a time zone where even -5 would not work?  And make the request with -5 and see what result you get?  Or if you can tell me which zone would give that result, I can update one of my user's time zone and test.  But I'd like you to check and see as well.

Comment: OK I will make some test and try to figure out what is going on, I let you know

Comment: I changed my user's time zone to LA, CA and I see the time data we get has -7 hour offset now.  But I don't think it matters because in our side we use UTC time, so whether it's -5 or -7 hour offset, the time we get is still the same.  But then the query seem to look for Dallas time, I still have to do -5 hours from the UTC time to modify query time in order to get the expected result.  We probably need to do -6 hours when Daylight saving is over and we have that covered by subtracting the hour found by using getOffset() on DateTime.

Comment: And my main concern is whether this is a permanent change or whether it's a bug that when it's fixed I should stop taking off the offset time.

Comment: The query always look for Dallas time -6 (In that time the data is stored in the database) And yes you are rigth you need to -5 from UTC and -6 when  the Daylight saving is over. the data was and is saved in the database with time -6, I am trying to figure out why you before had to add 5.

Comment: Basically when you perform you query you have to take in account that the request will look for data saved with time -6, then the API will convert the time of the result to the configured user profile timezone.

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests and I was able to reproduce this issue, It seems a bug, could you submit a ticket? Anyway, I will continue investigating about this. I will let you know any news.

Comment: Ticket 31897627 has been opened.  Please have someone fix this ASAP.  We have a product that uses this to detect new invoices and generate a bill and with this issue the customers may not get billed for some of the invoices.